# Use active cell as a reference to look up/right to find the first cell with specific back ground color

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to use the value in table header and row header as an input to calculate the value in active cell. For example column header has value 10 and row header as a value 10, the output would be 10*10 = 100.

I have managed to build a macro which I specify the row and column I want to use and it will loop through my selection of cells and do the calculation.

I want to further automate the code by asking the macro to lookup from my active cell in the selection and find the cell with specific color and take the column/row reference. The column and row header has specific color coding to them.

But I am not sure how to use find with combination of ActiveCell and asking it to lookup in a specific direction.

I need it to start searching from ActiveCell due to there might be multiple table in a tab and I want the calculation to be done for my selected range.

[Illustration of selection & active cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LPeu.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems to me that by introducing "color" you are not simplifying, but complicating the task (this is just an opinion! Perhaps, if you show a screenshot with your color scheme, I will give up my words). Please check if the `ActiveCell.CurrentRegion` construction will give you the desired result (check, for example, using Ctrl+G `? ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address` for some different Active Cells)

Comment: I agree, I might be complicating things, below is a illustration of what I wanted to do, I want to select the data area of the table and automate the population of column * row. I can't show the actual code I name it is in my company desktop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, CurrentRegion won't help here. Need to think about another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to solve this problem in the reverse order - not from the current cell to search for the table in which it is located, but to find all the tables on the sheet and select from them the one in which the cell fell.

The main work - finding tables on the sheet - will be done by **Function UsedAreas()**. A few years ago I found this code [here](https://strugglingtoexcel.com/2014/06/15/get-used-areas-range-excel-vba/), today, when I remembered it, I found it there again. (Thanks @Ejaz_Ahmed! Not sure that you are here now, but anyway - Thanks!)

The rest of the code is very simple:

```
Sub getCellInfo(aCell As Range, ByRef hRow As Variant, ByRef hColumn As Variant)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim EachArea As Range
Dim UsedAreasRange As Range
    Set ws = aCell.Worksheet
    Set UsedAreasRange = UsedAreas(ws.UsedRange)

    hRow = Empty
    hColumn = Empty

    For Each EachArea In UsedAreasRange.Areas
        If Not Application.Intersect(aCell, EachArea) Is Nothing Then
            hRow = ws.Cells(aCell.Row, EachArea.Column).Value2
            hColumn = ws.Cells(EachArea.Row, aCell.Column).Value2
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next EachArea
End Sub
```

For testing, I used this:

```
Sub a_getCellInfo_test()
Dim aCell As Range
Dim hR As Variant, hC As Variant
    Set aCell = ActiveCell
    Call getCellInfo(aCell, hR, hC)
    If IsEmpty(hR) Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & aCell.Address(False, False) & " not in a table"
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell " & aCell.Address(False, False) & " has Row '" & hR & "' and Column '" & hC & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```

Select any cell and run macro

*PS. I have no doubt that someone will demand to quote the **Function UsedAreas()** code under the pretext that the external resource may close and the code will be lost. I respect copyright. Anyone who wants to break them can go to the specified link and steal the code on their own.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "For each" loop to loop through each cell in your selection.

```
Sub test()

For Each loopcell In Selection
'If you already select an range of cell, "Selection" means the range you selected

    If loopcell.Interior.Color <> 65535 Then
           'your code if the cell is target color 65535 is yellow in color as an example
    End If
Next

End Sub
```